# Camel SFTP,quartz2 component gives:Cannot retrieve file :caused by GenericFileOperationFailedException,when polling multiple files from sftp

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I'm trying to poll files from sftp location using the below camel route and using quartz2 scheduler, after polling couple of files i'm getting a `GenricFileOperationFailedException caused by  java.io.IOException: Pipe closed`:

```
JaxbDataFormat dataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
dataFormat.setContext(JAXBContext.newInstance(MyBean.class));

    from(sftphost + sourcedirpath + 
                          "?password=" + password  
                        + "&username=" + userName  
                        + "&include=" + filePattern
                        + "&localWorkDirectory=" + localWorkingDirectory
                        + "&flatten=true"
                        + "&delete=true"
                        + "&scheduler=quartz2"
                        + "&scheduler.cron=0/45 * * * * ?" 
                        + "&stepwise=false"
                        + "&disconnect=true")
                .onException(Exception.class)
                    .to(sftphost + errdirpath + "?password=" + password + "&username=" + userName+"&disconnect=true")
                    .handled(true)
                    .end()
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Processing File : ${file:onlyname}").log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Before Unmarshalling XML").unmarshal(dataFormat)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "after UnMarshalling the XML").beanRef("service", "processData(${body}, ${file:name})")
                .to(sftphost + processedDirPAth + "?password=" + password + "&username=" + userName+ "&disconnect=true");
```

I face this issue only when I use the quartz2 Scheduler. The above camel route 
works completely fine when I use the '&delay=10000' parameter in the camel route.

Error Stacktrace:

```
2016-04-22 10:33:15,634 | WARN  | terface_Worker-1 | SftpConsumer                    ]
    | ?                                     ? | 264 - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Error processing file RemoteFile[/home/source/file_one.XML
    ] due to Cannot retrieve file: /home/source/file_one.XML. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperat
    ionFailedException - Cannot retrieve file: /home/source/file_one.XML]
    org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: /home/source/file_one.XML
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToFileInLocalWorkDirectory(SftpOperations.java:735)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFile(SftpOperations.java:591)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:396)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz2.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.execute(QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.java:59)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)[264:myBundle
    :1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    Caused by: 4:
            at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:1160)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1006)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:984)[264:myBundle
    :1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToFileInLocalWorkDirectory(SftpOperations.java:724)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
            at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)[:1.8.0_45]
            at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)[:1.8.0_45]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2882)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2908)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:1025)[264:myBundle:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
            ... 13 more
```

I have not used any other IO streams which are to be closed in the camel route.

Comment: May I ask what version of Camel are you using? this error looks very familiar to me..

Comment: Thanks for the response. The camel version i'm using is 2.15.2.

Comment: What if you take disconnect=true out of the parameters?

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri   I still have an issue, but I do not wanna connect to FTP after the my job is done

Comment: Can you create a unit test so I could reproduce it locally?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue for the SFTP user on the target machine. Please review https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4 for more details.

It's possible that it's only happening with the delay because the SSL context is not configured/initialized in the Camel FTP2 component immediately and you will need to delay a small time for that to happen before starting polling.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I get this issue only when I use the parameter 'scheduler=quartz2' and I do not get this issue when I use delay parameter '&delay=15000' in mycamel route.